# PEP440 compliant AND git describe info available from deployed package

Tags: python, git, continuous-integration

I would like to use use a *Version Identification* compliant with PEP440 but with a way to include the git information:

```
$ git describe --long
4.1-202-gab0f789
```

In PEP 440 there is a chapter about [dvcs](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/#dvcs-based-version-labels) but this is not clear to me how the .devN suffix can hold a non numeric hash like the above: `ab0f789`. I need a way to request from one of my scripts on production the `4.1-202-gab0f789` info, so where in `setup.py` can I put the project metadata?

Comment: The `.devN` suffix **shouldn't** have a hash, because *"hashes cannot be ordered reliably"* per the link you've shared.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That section tells you **not** to use the hash:

> As hashes cannot be ordered reliably **such versions are not permitted in the public version field.**

Emphasis mine.

They offer `.devN` as an alternative. If you are going to release developer versions from a git repository, number them, so `.dev0`, `.dev1`, etc. You could use tags to track these releases and track them back to specific revisions.

But if you read on, there is a way to tack on the hash as a [*local* version number](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/#local-version-identifiers):

> Identifying hash information may also be included in local version labels.

Add a `+`, then your hash (prefixed with `g` to ensure that an all-digit hash isn't compared as a number):

```
4.1.dev0+gab0f789
```

Local version numbers should only be used when creating a local non-indexed packaging or installation of your project however. Don't put a version with `+<hash>` on PyPI for example. But if you are producing packages from a continuous-integration server for developers to test, local version numbers are fine.

The [`setuptools-scm` project](https://pypi.org/project/setuptools-scm/) uses that exact scheme to include the git hash in versions based on non-tag git commits.

Comment: great, so with my example I can use  4.1.dev202+gab0f789

Comment: To anyone planning to actually rely on this, notice that currently pip removes leading 0s from the part after the `+` if all the characters happen to be digits. So `4.1.dev0+0069692` will be silently converted to `4.1.dev0+69692` on `pip install`. I would recommend using something like `{X}.{Y}.dev{Z}+git{SHA}` instead.

Comment: @RuRo that’s what the `g` is for in my answer.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ah, I guess `g` is not a valid sha character. I missed that. I still think, that it's better to mention this explicitly. Also, the next paragraph talks about `+<hash>` and not `+g<hash>`>

Comment: @RuRo: updated to make that more explicit.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with using the `dev` appendix for this is that for instance `4.1dev0+gab0f789` is semantically **before** the `4.1` release, while `4.1-202-gab0f789` from `git describe` actually mean that it is 202 commits **behind** `4.1`.

Comment: 'after' would be better word to use than 'behind' here. Behind also means "is older than", as in: is farther back in time. ... use the number after `dev` to sort by age, where _n_ is distance-from-tag